# VBA assigning new object to variable?

Tags: vba, object, variable-assignment

I'm trying create new object from a module class in VBA, and I have a small diffcult. Two line of assigning code, look like the same, but result is different.

[image]

I got a error message:

[image]

After that, I switch to use (1) instead of (2), error was fixed.

[image]

But I dont understand; **Why do they have this difference?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not use `Dim` to declare the specific type of a variable you may subsequently change the variable to another type, for example after;

`set aosh = new AOSHRatioQuery`

You could mutate the variable to a string;

`aosh = "A pint of milk"`

As the `sendAsyncRequest` method expects a `AOSHRatioQuery` as its 2nd argument & the VBA compiler knows that it cannot guarantee that the `aosh` variable will actually contain an instance of that type, type safety is violated & the *Type Mismatch* error is raised to prevent `sendAsyncRequest` from receiving garbage it cannot interpret.

Explicitly typing with `Dim aosh as new AOSHRatioQuery` tells the compiler that `aosh` is guaranteed to always be `AOSHRatioQuery` instance or `Nothing` (attempting to assign it to another type will raise an error) so it can be passed safely.

Answer (score 4):

`Dim` declares a variable, `Set` instantiates it.

So, it's a good practice to always have `Dim` before `Set`.

Answer (score 3):

In VBA, you have to declare variables using the Dim keyword, and then defining their data types with the As keyword.  That's just how its syntax works.  As a general form:

```
Dim <variableName> As <dataType>
```